# Emulating 'return' in macro

Tags: macros, return

Is there any standard compliant way to emulate 'return' with macro?

Currently, I'm trying to wrapping _alloca function to emulate variable length array on stack (which is supported in C99) with macro in C++. Since the _alloca function manipulates stack pointer, I think inline function isn't suitable solution for this time.

Below is the current code that I've written.

```
template <typename T>
inline void __placement_new_array(T arr[], const size_t size) {
    assert(size > 0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        new (&arr[i]) T;
    }
}

template <typename T>
class __arraydtor
{
    public:
        __arraydtor(T arr[], size_t size) : arr_(arr), size_(size) {}
        ~__arraydtor() {
            for (size_t i = size_ - 1; i != (size_t)(-1); i--) {
                arr_[i].~T();
            }
        }

    private:
        T* arr_;
        size_t size_;
};

#define stack_alloc(size) _alloca(size)

#define stacknew(ptr, type, size) \
    ptr = static_cast<type*>(stack_alloc(sizeof(type) * size));\
    __placement_new_array(ptr, size);\
    __arraydtor<type> __##type##_dtor_instance(ptr,size)

...

    type* pos;

    stacknew(pos, type, size);
```

I think the code is fairly usable even for now (it works for most type at least in vs2005), but ultimately I want to acheive the macro that can be used like below -

```
pos = stacknew(type, size);
```

(Of course pos = stacknew type[size]; would be more cool but I don't think there is a way to acheive it with any C++ compiler)

Since the macro contains some declaration, emulating 'return' is impossible in the current form - it might be impossible or needs a different approach. But I'm lack of experience for using macro, I can not judge whether it's possible or not.

Also I want to note that above code is not safe when the ctor of the target array throws exception - I'd also be grateful if someone suggests a way to improve the macro.

Comment: Forget that macros exist in C++. Yes, they are seductive, but they make an already arcane language even worser. If it is hard to code, it will be even harder to understand and is likely to break when something changes.

Comment: @msw, +1 for the avoidance of macros, minus several billion for the use of the phrase "even worser". Not really, just the +1 :-)

Comment: I stole "even worser" from Spalding Gray so I can't even take credit for the phrase. Nor shall I take the blame should you start using it in conversation (and you will use it, it falls off the tongue nicely).

Comment: Usually I am also an macro critic as you and try to avoid to use it. But in this case I can't use function, class, or any other abstraction mechanism except macro to avoid code duplication, which is much more greater evil than carefully designed/used macro (of course, it's just my opinion...).

Comment: code reuse is not more eviler than a macro.

Comment: btw imo it's cleaner to put your placement new function & array dtor class into a single smart-pointer-ish class

Comment: It looks like the RAII class can be turned into something like placement_array class. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `,` operator:

```
v = (expr1, expr2); // evaluate both expressions, return rightmost
```

Comment: Comma operator may be helpful if dtor part(which contains declaration) is seperated. Thanks :)